# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm doing a validation by regex from a request, this validation is to check that the parameter that is sent is an IP.

My rules are as follows:

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\usuarios;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class storeVPN extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [            
            'segmentwan' => 'regex:/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/',
            'segmentlan' => 'regex:/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/',

        ];
    }
```

the debugger shows me that the error is in this line

the debugger shows me that the error is in this line

```
return preg_match($parameters[0], $value) > 0;
```

y el error completo es el siguiente

```
 * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRegex($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if (! is_string($value) && ! is_numeric($value)) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'regex');

        return preg_match($parameters[0], $value) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Validate that a required attribute exists.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRequired($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return false;
        } elseif (is_string($value) && trim($value) === '') {
            return false;
        } elseif ((is_array($value) || $value instanceof Countable) && count($value) < 1) {
            return false;
        } elseif ($value instanceof File) {
            return (string) $value->getPath() !== '';
        }
```

Comment: Validating IP addresses with regex is... erm... unnecessary. `ip2long()` will return false on an invalid address string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you have [ip](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-ip) validation rule so you can use:

```
    return [            
        'segmentwan' => 'ip',
        'segmentlan' => 'ip',
    ];
```

Also to be honest when I'm looking at your code I don't see the error. Are you sure error is with those 2 regexes?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Validation rules. When you are using regex you need to use Array instead of pipe delimiter.

```
return [            
    'segmentwan' => [ 'regex:/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/'],
    'segmentlan' => [ 'regex:/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/'],
];
```

> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify
>   rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the
>   regular expression contains a pipe character.

**UPDATE**

If you are validating IP address than laravel provides three validation options.

> **ip:** 
>   The field under validation must be an IP address.
>
> **ipv4:**
>   The field under validation must be an IPv4 address.
>
> **ipv6:**
>   The field under validation must be an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using regex to validate IPs; you can use `filter_var()` built-in function instead

It has many flags including `FILTER_FLAG_IPV4` for ipv4 & `FILTER_FLAG_IPV6` for ipv6 ... Ofcourse you can mix flags so you are able to check both